# Document Database Relationship design

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I am trying to convert a relational MySQL database into a document database, as a mandatory school assignment.

As shown in the ER diagram the idea of the SQL database is that a user can be registered as a regular user and a restaurant, but not both.
Users can then place orders on restaurants. The products of each order then gets stored in a junction table.

To convert this to a Document database (MongoDB) my idea is to have the following collections:

```
Users
orders:[{products:[{product},{product}]}]

Restaurants
orders:[{products:[{product},{product}]}]
```

Each time a new order is placed it will be saved in the users collection and restaurant collection.

But i am not sure if it is even necesarry to have both a Users and a Restaurants collection, or if you could just have Users and then specify if the user is a restaurant.

And i am also not sure how i can establish a relationship, so if a user deletes an order it will also be deleted in the Restaurants order array.

I recently failed my Database exam (among other things) because i had the structure of 3 collections like this:

```
Users
{_id etc, orders:[{_id: id of the order}]}

Restaurants
{_id etc, orders:[{_id: id of the order}]}

Orders:
{id etc, products: [{product},{product}]}
```

Here each time a user makes an order it is saved in the order collection and a _id is stored in the restaurants and users arrays.

I was told this is wrong, so how would be the correct way to design a Document Database
What i am trying to achive is to store as much data in each collection but still have a connection between orders, restaurants and users so there will be no wrong data in the database.

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to implement a clearly relational model in a non-relational database?

Comment: @mustaccio Because my teacher told me to do so